# Adminer mssql errors

Tags: php, sql-server, adminer

I'm trying to get all tables to display in Adminer so I don't have to remote into the Windows Server to look at tables and query from the MS SQL DB that I'm working with. I got this error when I click "Select Tablename" to view the data on any table. What do you think I need to do to fix this?

> ! ) Warning: mssql_query(): message: Unicode data in a Unicode-only
>   collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library
>   (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier. (severity 16) in
>   /public_html/main/manage/adminer.php on line 665 Call Stack

```
Time     Memory       Function             Location 1   
0.0257  3534208       {main}( )          ../adminer.php:0 2 
0.0719  4047480       fields( )          ../adminer.php:1624 3  
0.0719  4048088       get_rows( )        ../adminer.php:724 4   
0.0719  4048368       Min_DB->query( )   ../adminer.php:47 5    
0.0719  4048464       mssql_query ( )    ../adminer.php:665
```

On my Linux server I've got mssql, mysql, mysqli, pdo, pdo_dblib, and pdo_mysql installed. I can pull data to web pages successfully using pdo-dblib.

EDIT: Solution was to change the version in [global] in freetds.conf from 4.2 to 8.0. That solved my problem.

Comment: When you say `mssql` is installed, what specifically is the package? FreeTDS? If so, what version? From the error message it seems clear that a newer version of the driver in use is required.

Comment: @beargle Sometimes you just need a quick second opinion from another person to guide you in the right direction. I'm using FreeTDS version 8.0 but forgot to change the version in [global] in freetds.conf from 4.2 to 8.0. That solved my problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Good to hear :) Don't forget to put that in as an answer and accept it so others can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I'm using FreeTDS version 8.0 but forgot to change the version in [global] in freetds.conf from 4.2 to 8.0. That solved my problem.

Credit goes to beargle above for pointing me in the right direction.